# App Engine & Cloud Storage How to save file with the permission with a public link programmatically

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

I write a function to create thumbnail image, but the thumbnail image don't have the public link, even if the original file have the permission `User`-`allUsers`-`Reader` and public link `https://storage.googleapis.com/{buckets}/{filename}` for all user to access the file.

How can I add this permission to my thumbnail image.

```
public static void thumbnailImage(String filename, int width, int height) throws IOException{
    GcsService gcsService = GcsServiceFactory.createGcsService(new RetryParams.Builder()
              .initialRetryDelayMillis(10)
              .retryMaxAttempts(10)
              .totalRetryPeriodMillis(15000)
              .build());
    AppIdentityService appIdentity = AppIdentityServiceFactory.getAppIdentityService();
    ImagesService imagesService = ImagesServiceFactory.getImagesService();
    // Make an image from a Cloud Storage object, and transform it.
    BlobstoreService blobstoreService = BlobstoreServiceFactory.getBlobstoreService();
    BlobKey blobKey = blobstoreService.createGsBlobKey("/gs/" + appIdentity.getDefaultGcsBucketName() +"/"+ filename);

    Image thumb = null;
    try{
        Image blobImage = ImagesServiceFactory.makeImageFromBlob(blobKey);          
        Transform resize = ImagesServiceFactory.makeResize(width, height);
        thumb = imagesService.applyTransform(resize, blobImage);

    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    String extension = Files.getFileExtension(filename);
    filename = stripExtension(filename);
    filename = String.format("%1$s_%2$s.%3$s", filename, thumbnail, extension);

    if(thumb!=null)
    // Write the transformed image back to a Cloud Storage object.
    gcsService.createOrReplace(
        new GcsFilename(appIdentity.getDefaultGcsBucketName(), filename),
        new GcsFileOptions.Builder().mimeType("image/jpeg").build(),
        ByteBuffer.wrap(thumb.getImageData()));
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the GcsFileOption parameter "acl" to make this visible to others. So change that bit at the end to this:

```
new GcsFileOptions.Builder().mimeType("image/jpeg").acl("public-read").build(),
```

The public link will be the same storage.googleapis.com/bucket/object pattern, except with object being the thumbnail's name.

Comment: Thank it work for me, but I can not find any related document about acl function and it value, How to remove the `public-read` or change to other permission.?

Comment: That ACL field takes any of the GCS "predefined ACLs" (in their gsutil/XML API form). The full list is defined here: https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/lists#predefined-acl

GCS supports more elaborate ACL options, but I'm not sure that particular client exposes those options.

Comment: Hi, now I have another problems. but thumbnail file size is larger than original file, Please help. I ask another question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38358649/app-engine-and-cloud-storage-i-generate-thumbnail-image-has-larger-file-size-tha